# NPE in Kafka JDBC Source connector when using inner query

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using MYSQL5.7 and JDBCSourceConnector 5.3.x. I am using the custom query mode, but looks like I am not using the correct syntax to select the incremental column (Id in my case) in my query. That seems to be the cause for the NPE I posted below.
I am using this as a reference:
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/560

Here is the config (truncated) where i try to select the incremental column id and the other config values.

```
query= select events.eventId, events.* from (select ES.id as eventId, ES.action,  U.name FROM eventsource as ES INNER JOIN user U ON ES.user_id = U.id where U.email='xxx') events . 
mode=incrementing 
incrementing.column.name=events.eventId 
quote.sql.identifiers=never
```

Can somene please provide the appropriate syntax to overcome this error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingCriteria.extractOffsetIncrementedId(TimestampIncrementingCriteria.java:237)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingCriteria.extractValues(TimestampIncrementingCriteria.java:195)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.extractRecord(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:192)
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask.poll(JdbcSourceTask.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2020-01-28 14:14:37,251] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=connect-event-source1-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:173)
```

Comment: What if you did `select events.eventId AS timestamp`, then selecting that column?

Comment: Thank u for ur response...good idea. I will try that out.

Comment: That did not work.

Comment: Hmm. Are you able to download jdbc connector source code to set up a breakpoint at the line in the stacktrace?

Comment: Finally got it to work following the comments on this link: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/691